# How to say "I look forward to hearing from you" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, epistula

It is sometimes appropriate to add "I look forward to hearing from you" at the end of a letter or other similar communication.
I am looking for a phrase that says more "I am happy if you react to this letter in some way" rather than "please write back".
(To be precise, I really mean "please come to Latin.SE".)
What would be an idiomatic way to express this in classical Latin?
The Roman letters from antiquity must have a phrase that has this effect, but I'm not familiar with any.

A direct translation might be something like *Expecto mihi de te audire licere*, "I await a chance to hear about you".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Is this to a close friend, an acquaintance, or something more formal?

Comment: @C.M.Weimer What I had in mind is something like a hobby-related acquaintance or a distant colleague. For example, consider sending an email to a Latinist you met a year ago in an event, telling them about this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would something as simple as

> Té (vós) summé præstolámur.

or

> Scító (-óte) té (vós) valde exspectátum (-ós).

do the trick? (I'm going with your real meaning rather than the specific sentence you asked for.)

(*Præstolor* seems to take the dative or the accusative indiscriminately.)

Comment: I will accept this answer for now. If someone hits the nail with an attested classical idiom, I will have to unaccept.

Comment: I will brace myself for the possibility. :)

Comment: By the way, I'm going here on Wednesday, so if I learn anything new I'll update or post a new answer. http://www.latin.org/programs/rusticatio/tironum/

Comment: That looks interesting. I might consider attending one of those if they were closer to me.

Comment: Oh, and please remember to tell about our site there!